# Kohana_HTTP_Exception [ 404 ]: The requested URL Dave was not found on this server

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

A similar question has been asked before but solution to that didn't help me. I created a file "dave.php" in application/classes/Controller/ folder and I renamed the controller as well. Here's the code in dave.php file:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') OR die('No Direct Script Access');

Class Controller_Dave extends Controller
{
public function action_index()
{
    echo 'hello, world!';
}
}
```

kohana/index.php/dave - but I am still geting that error. Any ideas why?

Comment: I think your Controller folder needs to be lower cased

Comment: never assume case-insensitivity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you use Kohana 3.3, so the file name should be `Dave.php` not `dave.php`

Answer (score 0):

That is my htaccess

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteBase /
>
> RewriteRule ^(application|modules|system) - [F,L]
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}
>   !-d
>
> RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]

Check, is apache mod_rewrite enable and loaded at phpinfo();
In My case I've just enable mod_rewrite at apache.

```
 sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

and than restart

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Check .htaccess rules.

And note, that  Controllers names  are case sensitivity.